# How can i sort the results of a lucene search between multiple indexes?

Tags: java, lucene

I have two lucene indexes and i need to search on the two indexes. How can i execute a search in multiple lucene indexes? How can i sort these results?

Thanks,
Luiz Costa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basic code.. just typed it up check out the doc for more details

```
IndexSearcher[] searchers = new IndexSearcher[2];
searchers[0] = new IndexSearcher(searchDirOne);
searchers[1] = new IndexSearcher(searchDirTwo);

MultiSearcher searcher = new MultiSearcher(searchers);

Query query = QueryParser.Parse("foo","bar" , new StandardAnalyzer());

Hits hits = searcher.Search(query);
```

[MultiSearcher Documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiSearcher.html)

Comment: thanks Aeron, it's works. But now, i am trying sorting these results.